# Bernoulli head losses

Tags: fluid-mechanics, bernoulli

For a Venturi, I calculated total head theoretically and experimentally. I noticed that the last point along the Venturi has not got the same as the start point total head? Shouldn’t it be the same due to Conservation of energy?

Comment: it has to be less after the venturi than before it.  Head loss along the venture it will be based on the shape, but actual pressure will change with velocity.  Fluid loses energy going through the venturi.

Comment: Hi, thank you. So am I right in saying that there will always be losses?